# centos route problems, can't connect to network

Tags: networking, route

I have an issue with CentOS route... maybe someone can help me to figure it out, how to simple configure route... I have an dedicated ip adress e.g. 13.97.82.85 my netmask is  255.255.255.192 and gw is 13.97.82.65 all I want to do to connect to the internet... Now I have route like this:

```
Destination             Gateway       Genmask          Flags   Metric   Ref    Use   Iface
13.97.82.64             *             255.255.255.192  U       0        0        0   seth0
default                 13.97.82.65   0.0.0.0          UG      0        0        0   seth0
```

I can't understand from where comes 13.97.82.64 IP adress? in network configuration files (ifcfg...) everything seems correct, also I set `NOZEROCONF=yes`.

With DNS everything seems correct, I can resolve address, but I can't ping...

Maybe, someone could help me?

Comment: 13.97.82.64 is the start of your subnet that you reside in - in case, a /26 subnet. Can you at least ping the gateway?

Comment: Thanks for answering me. I can't ping my default gateway. Maybe other suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can`t ping the gateway it propably is no gateway. Where did you get the gateway-address from?

Comment: from my data center, on other servers working without any issue... Thank You.

Comment: ups... I forgot to swich off firewall, no it's ok. I can ping default gateway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your config

```
Network:   13.97.82.64/26
HostMin:   13.97.82.65
HostMax:   13.97.82.126
Broadcast: 13.97.82.127
Hosts/Net: 62
```

13.97.82.64 is network address for /26 net. Route table always contain route to base net

> I can resolve address, but I can't ping...

If DNS-resolver placed  inside your /26 net - your packets for resolving doesn't leave it. For ICMP-pings situation differ - pACKETS must go after default-gw. Possible troubles

- icmp echo-reply disabled on gw (traceroute some-kbown-exrertal-ip for test)
- IP-forward disabled on GW (traceroute again)
- smth. more, have to think

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I will try to call to my data center, maybe they add some restrictions or smth to this server. Thank you!